# Problem with implied verbs

Tags: meaning

I'm having trouble understanding this paragraph:

> 抗争相手に浮上している元世界ヘビー級王者のドルフ・ジグラー（３６）を「サイズは自分のほうがあるけど、機動力とかレスリングのベースは信頼できる技術は持ってるなと思いますね」と評したが、スマックダウンには新日本プロレス時代のライバル・ＡＪスタイルズを筆頭に強敵が揃う。

I think there's an implied verb in 抗争相手に浮上 and after ドルフ・ジグラー（３６）を. Also I'm not sure whether the speaker is talking about himself or his oponent(ドルフ・ジグラー) in this line:  (the speaker is taller than ドルフ・ジグラー)

> 「サイズは自分のほうがあるけど、機動力とかレスリングのベースは信頼できる技術は持ってるなと思いますね」

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think a verb is implied somewhere. 抗争相手に浮上している is a relative clause that modifies 元世界級ヘビー王者. (Alternatively, you can think 抗争相手に浮上している and 元世界ヘビー級王者の independently modify ジグラー.)

> [抗争相手に浮上している→]元世界王者
>   A former world heavyweight champion who has emerged as a rival (of the interviewee)

ドルフ・ジグラー is the object of 評した.

> ドルフ・ジグラーを「～」と評した
>   (The interviewee) commented about Dolph Ziggler, "～"
>
> 抗争相手に浮上している元世界ヘビー級王者のドルフ・ジグラー（３６）を「～」と評した
>   (The interviewee) commented about Dolph Ziggler, a former world heavyweight champion who has emerged as his rival, "～".

In the quote, the speaker is of course talking about Ziggler's skill ("Although I am taller, I think *Ziggler* has a skill ...").

Comment: @Jon I edited my answer as to what modifies what.